# Como verifico se um switch está ativado?

Tags: java, xml

Eu estou tentando fazer um programa que possui alguns elementos da casa, como lâmpadas. Em uma tela eu quero que mostre todos os elementos, se esses estão ligados ou desligados. Possuo alguns switchs e quero colocar um texto na tela principal equivalente ao status deles.

Esse é meu XML com o `switch`:

```
<Switch
android:id="@+id/switch1"
android:layout_width="140dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="Lampada" />
```

E aqui eu tento verificar o status dele:

```
public void homeFragment () {

    switchQuarto = view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    elemento = view.findViewById(R.id.elemento);
    status = view.findViewById(R.id.status);
    elemento.setText(Html.fromHtml("Status da Lampada: "));
    if (switchQuarto.isActivated()) {
        status.setText(Html.fromHtml("Ligada"));
    } else {
        status.setText(Html.fromHtml("Desligada"));
    }
}
```

Ele trava no `switchQuarto.isActivated()`, como posso fazer essa verificação ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que adicionar um listener é a melhor forma na minha opinião, pois assim sempre que ele mudar, ele aciona uma ação.

```
switchQuarto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(switchQuarto.isChecked()){
                   // Aqui você faz a ação
                   status.setText(Html.fromHtml("Ligada"));
                } else {
                   status.setText(Html.fromHtml("Desligada"));
                }
            }
        });
```